# Symfony 2.8 and PHP 7.4: Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Composer is at latest version

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.8

I am trying to update a symfony 2.8 application to use PHP 7.4, but when I try to clear the cache `php app/console cache:clear` I get the following warning:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

which results in "script exited with non-zero code". That messes up the whole automation process of Jenkins. The solutions I ran at were generally a simple composer update, but after I did this and updated composer to the latest version (currently 2.0.7), the error still persists, and I'm sure it's not a composer issue, as this warning crashes even the symfony-only `cache:clear` command. I was thinking about creating my own fork of symfony from this particular version branch and fixing the errors myself, but I cannot find the exact spot this `continue` occurs.

How to eliminate this error, or at least how to debug the whole process, so I can fix the error myself?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the message that is returned after running `php app/console cache:clear --verbose`. I don't see any sign of potential continue bug. Does any of you see something like this?

```
Exception trace:
() at 
/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2636
Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError() at
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:169

 require() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:169
 Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() at n/a:n/a
 spl_autoload_call() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:160
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->__construct() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:850
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1711
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() at /var/www/html/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:183
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManager() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:9401
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosUser_EntityManagerService() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:2945
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosUser_UserManagerService() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:9219
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getValidator_BuilderService() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:9201
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getValidatorService() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:8349
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSonata_Adminbundle_Command_ExplainadmincommandService() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:295
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:147
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:112
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->all() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:66
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/app/console:28
```

Comment: That looks like an issue in `doctrine/orm` - which version are you using? To check for potentially outdated package versions, you can run `composer outdated`

Comment: The warning message is actually something introduced in 7.2 and yes it messed up quite a few things.  As mentioned in the answer, S2.8 and it's related components (especially Doctrine) was never updated to deal with all the quirks that gradually build up.  If you check Doctrine's UnitOfWork code you will find several very complex and hard to follow switch statements.  They don't have errors but 7.2 thinks they might. You will find plenty of similar sorts of posts if you do a bit of searching.

Comment: @NicoHaase I get a few messages like this one: `Package doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.` and I guess this is that one package that causes trouble. doctrine/orm seems to be ok.

Comment: What do you mean by "ok"? Can you add the exact version number of `doctrine/orm` to your question? As far as I see, the error originates exactly there

Comment: `"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",` which is at least not abandoned :) Any version of `doctrine/orm` higher that ^2.5 requires `symfony/console` ~3.0|~4.0, which conflicts with my symfony 2.8 installation.

Comment: Well, even if this is not the version you are using, but only the version constraint which allows multiple versions to be installed: if you are on such an old version of a package, you cannot expect that is is compatible with later PHP versions

Comment: Yes, I know, but I really don't want to dig so deep and updating the whole application. After changing UnitOfWork:2636 from `continue` to `continue 2`, another error popped up: UnitOfWork:2665. Doing the same thing for the second error seems to have fixed the issue and the cache is smoothly cleared now. As those files are in `vendor/` directory, the fix I need is probably going to be a private fork of `doctrine/orm`. Thanks @NicoHaase :)

Comment: Well, this might be a first quick solution, but you should better update the packages properly - or stick to PHP 7.2

Comment: Cannot stick to PHP 7.2, because of the GDPR. Cannot update all packages, because I'm on a very tight schedule. I'm going for the quick fix :) The application definitely needs to be updated and it will happen at some point, just not today :)

Comment: @EmilAvramov In technical terms this is what is known as being screwed.  Even if you fork the Doctrine package and fix the warning you will just run into FOSUserBundle issues.  And probably more as well.  Good luck.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why should any PHP version interfere with GDPR? Working daily with PHP, based in Germany, I haven't heard of such a connection yet

Comment: I don't know about this in much detail, but as far as our company's lawyer told me, GDPR requires us to keep not more that one major version of the technologies used behind. It's connected to security issues, I think. So, with PHP 8 being released last month, we should be at at least PHP 7.4. This is what I've been told, haven't checked if it is true, though :)

Comment: ....so, shouldn't this also affect Symfony itself? I understand such needs, but if updating to another PHP version breaks your application (as you've told in the initial question), shouldn't there be a consideration of multiple arguments? Breaking your application, putting you in need of dirty hacks, should not be enforced by your lawyer

Comment: That's supposed to be just a temporary fix, symfony itself will also be updated, though I'm not really sure if the symfony's versions are affected by GDPR or only the underlying language and webserver (as well as the OS). But, as you said, such dirty hacks should not be tolerated, moreover enforced, and that's why a full application update is scheduled now, we just have to hold the line a few more weeks after PHP 8 was released :)

Answer (score 2):

Symfony 2.8 is no longer supported, and it hasn't been made compatible with PHP 7.4 (as this was release after the last fixes for Symfony 2.8). You could check **where exactly** that error occurs and try to fix it (usually the full error message should contain such information), or you have to update Symfony 2.8 as well to a supported version.

**Edit**: after you've presented more details, I assume that you are using `doctrine/orm` in v2.5.14. This has been released in Dec 2017, and this was the latest version to be compatible with Symfony 2.8. As PHP 7.3 (in which the deprecation of `continue` with `switch` was [introduced](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.core.continue-targeting-switch)) was released in Dec 2018, it's not a surprise that such a problem has not been fixed in the ORM package.

You should either stick to PHP 7.2, or update Symfony, Doctrine, and whatever bundles you are using to more recent ones.

Comment: Check my edit, please, I added the message I get on `--verbose`